# trying to add a wave effect to a vertex plane

Tags: c++, directx, vertex-shader

so what this is supposed to do it create a plane that moves in a sine wave pattern (code that has nothing to do with making it a wave is not shown as it all works fine) and while the plane renders fine it just stays as a flat plane. I'm assuming the problem is that the frame time isn't being called by the vertex shader so I'd like to know how to do that because I'm confused as to why this isn't working
[image]
the plane I'm trying to make into a wave ^

manipulation_shader_vs.hlsl

```
cbuffer TimeBufferType : register(b1)
{
    float time;
};

OutputType main(InputType input)
{
    OutputType output;
    input.position.y = sin(input.position.x + time);
    input.normal = float3(-cos(input.position.x + time), 1, 0);
    ...
```

timer.cpp

```
void Timer::frame()
{
    INT64 currentTime;
    float timeDifference;

    // Query the current time.
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&currentTime);
    timeDifference = (float)(currentTime - startTime);
    frameTime = timeDifference / ticksPerS;

    // Calc FPS
    frames += 1.f;
    elapsedTime += frameTime;
    if (elapsedTime > 1.0f)
    {
        fps = frames / elapsedTime;
        frames = 0.0f;
        elapsedTime = 0.0f;
    }
    
    // Restart the timer.
    startTime = currentTime;

    return;
}


float Timer::getTime()
{
    return frameTime;
}
```

manipulationshader.cpp

```
void ManipulationShader::setShaderParameters(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, const XMMATRIX& worldMatrix, const XMMATRIX& viewMatrix, const XMMATRIX& projectionMatrix, ID3D11ShaderResourceView* texture, Light* light, Timer* time)
{
    TimeBufferType* timePtr;
    deviceContext->Map(TimeBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    timePtr = (TimeBufferType*)mappedResource.pData;
    timePtr->time = time->getTime();
    deviceContext->Unmap(TimeBuffer, 0);
    deviceContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &TimeBuffer);
}
```

Comment: a [mre] would probably be helpful

Comment: In your ::setShaderParameters() function, the cbuffer in the pixel shader is being updated with the time value, but not in the vertex shader where vertex displacement takes place.

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio thanks. no idea how I missed that. I meant to update the vertex shader and not the pixel shader. still doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic "0 vs. 1 base" bug.

In your shader you have the constant buffer bound to slot 1.

```
cbuffer TimeBufferType : register(b1)
```

In your code, you are binding the constant buffer to slot 0.

```
deviceContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &TimeBuffer);
```

and as noted in the comments by another StackOverflow user, you are binding it only for the pixel shader, not the vertex shader. You are therefore missing this method call:

```
deviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &TimeBuffer);
```

It's also important in Direct3D coding to *always* check functions that return `HRESULT` for success or failure. It's very hard to debug complex programs otherwise. For many cases, a "fast-fatal" solution like [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed) works well. You can also use a conditional like the following:

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource = {};
if (SUCCEEDED(deviceContext->Map(TimeBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0,
    &mappedResource)))
{
    auto timePtr = reinterpret_cast<TimeBufferType*>(mappedResource.pData);
    timePtr->time = time->getTime();
    deviceContext->Unmap(TimeBuffer, 0);
}
```

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com).

> One additional recommendation: Take a look at [StepTimer](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/StepTimer) for your 'animation time' computation. Time computation is quite tricky, and there are quite a number of edge-cases you are not dealing with. For more, see [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/understanding-game-time-revisited/).